# How to set ImageView drawable Size based on Its parent view size?

Tags: android, view, imageview, drawable, scale

I have imageView inside a relative layout. And when i create the activity i run thread to grap bitmap from the internet and set the imageView.

What i want is to resize the bitmap to scale based on relative view size while keeping the aspect ratio. The code for resizing the image is working but what i do is i get the relative view size by calling `myRelativeView.getWidth()` & `myRelativeView.getHeight()` and i feel that i should not do that because the docs say it could return 0. So what is the best way to retrieve the size of the relative view in this case ?

Comment: Is the relative layout the whole screen or a strict proportion?

Comment: No, there's an action bar and another relative layout in the viewGroup.

Comment: Right, but are they proportional to the screen? If so see my answer below.

Comment: What if you just set the scaleType:fitXY or what suits you in the ImageView - and set both height and width to fill_parent and let android handling the scaling.

Comment: Yeah, but i think scaleType:fitXY it does not keep the aspect raio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FIX for your request :]

If you don't want to change size:
set your `ImageView` `scaleType` to "matrix"

If you want to change size but keep aspect ratio:
set your `ImageView` `scaleType` to "fitCenter" (or "fitStart", "fitEnd")

To change in code:

```
ImageView image;

image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.yourImageView1);

image.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
```

To Change in XML:
Example

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="ic_launcher"/>
```

Comment: +1.  fitCenter should scale the image to fit and keep the aspect ratio.

Comment: but here also it spanned drawable to View size..is there any way to set drawable without spanning it?

Answer (score 0):

If the layout is in a proportion with the whole screen you can try:

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        width = display.getWidth()
```

//*proportion;or -dp;
            height = display.getHeight()
//*proportion2;or -dp;

Comment: The layout is not taking the whole screen.  there's an action bar and another relative layout.

Comment: I understand that, proportion means say 4/5 of the height and 3/5s of the width.

Comment: No, there's other layouts that is measured using dp.